# Pole of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, singularity

How can I show that $f(z) = \frac{1}{(2\cos(z)-2+z^2)^2}$ has a pole at $z=0$ and find its order? So I know I need to find an $m$ so that $\lim_{z \to 0} (z-0)^m f(z)$ is finite, but this is where I'm having trouble. I tried multiplying out the bottom of the function, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Note: I haven't covered series yet, so I'm attempting to show this solely using limits.

Comment: Umm... it doesn't. $f(0) = 1$.

Comment: May be $f(z)=\frac{1}{(2(\cos z-1)+z^2)^2}$

Comment: You are correct, I fixed the issue in the question.

Comment: Suggestion: Multiplying out the denominator isn't very helpful. Instead, Taylor expand the cosine.

Comment: If I Taylor expand the cosine, I get $\frac{1}{\left({2\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{-1^nz^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)}-2+z^2\right)^2}$, then I expanded the bottom to get $(2(1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-\frac{z^6}{6!}\ldots)-2+z^2)^2 = (2(\frac{z^4}{4!}-\frac{z^6}{6!}+\frac{z^8}{8!}+\ldots))^2 = (\frac{z^4}{12}-\frac{z^6}{360}+\frac{z^8}{20160}\ldots)$ is this correct? And then where do I go from here?

Comment: To show there is a pole at $z=0$, simply note that $|f(z)|$ becomes unbounded as $z$ goes to $0$. For its order, you're on right track. I don't know how you found square of a series, but continuing from the last second equality, $z^8$ can be taken out of square. The $m$ you wanted to find is $8$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the Maclaurin series of $\cos z$ to see the denominator equals $z^8g(z)$ for some analytic $g$ in a neighborhood of of $0$ such that $g(0)\ne 0.$